# Compute the maximum length of an increasing digital subsequence given an array of digits

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

Consider the following exercise from [chapter *Dynamic Programming* in the book *Algorithms*](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/03-dynprog.pdf) by Jeff Erickson.

> Let $D[1 .. n]$ be an array of digits, each an integer between $0$ and $9$. A **digital subsequence** of $D$ is a sequence of positive integers composed in the usual way from disjoint substrings of $D$. For example, $3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 32, 38, 46, 64, 83, 279$ is a digital subsequence of the first several digits of $\pi$:$$ \underline 3 , 1, \underline 4 , 1, \underline 5 , 9, 2, \underline 6 , 5, 3, 5, \underline 8 , \underline 9 , 7, 9, \underline{3, 2} , 3, 8, \underline{4, 6} , 2, \underline{6, 4} , 3, 3, \underline{8, 3 }, \underline {2, 7, 9}$$ The length of a digital subsequence is the number of integers it contains, not the number of digits; the preceding example has length $12$. As usual, a digital subsequence is **increasing** if each number is larger than its predecessor.
>
> Describe and analyze an efficient algorithm to compute the longest increasing digital subsequence of $D$. [*Hint: Be careful about your computational assumptions. How long does it take to compare two k-digit numbers?*]
>
> For full credit, your algorithm should run in $O(n^4)$ time; faster algorithms are worth extra credit. The fastest algorithm I know for this problem runs in $O(n^{3/2}log n)$ time; achieving this bound requires several tricks, both in the design of the algorithm and in its analysis, but nothing outside the scope of this class.

My main question is how I can define my subproblems? I guess we must have an 3D array like:
$$DP[i][j][k]$$
but I can't define $DP[i][j][k]$ very well.

Comment: 3-dimensional subproblems are unlikely to yield an algorithm with $O(n^4)$ time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\overline{D[i..j]}$ denote the number formed by the digits $D[i..j]$. For example, if $D=(1,5,7,4,8,3)$, then $\overline{D[2..2]}=5$ and $\overline{D[2..4]}=574$.

##### The subprolems

Let $DP[i][j]$ with $1\le i\le j\le n$ be the maximum length of a digital subsequence of $D$ the last number of which is $\overline{D[i..j]}$.

The recurrence relation is

$$DP[i][j]=1+\max_{\ell<i,\, \overline{D[k..l]}<\overline{D[i..j]}} DP[k][\ell]$$
where the default value of $\max$ is $0$, i.e., if there is no arguments, $\max$ is $0$.

The answer is the maximum of all $DP[i][j]$'s.

##### Analysis on time-complexity

Since both $i$ and $j$ range from $1$ to at most $n$, there are at most $n^2$ $DP[i][j]$'s (subproblems).

Let us check how much computation is needed to compute one entry $DP[i][j]$.

We need to list all $k,l$ such that $\ell<i$ and $\overline{D[k..l]}<\overline{D[i..j]}$. Compute the actual number of digits in $\overline{D[i..j]}$, i.e., without the leading zeros. let it be $p$.

- For each $gap=0,1,2,\cdots, p-1$, we can let $(k,l)=(s, s+gap)$, where $s=0, 1, \cdots, i-gap-1$. $\overline{D[k..l]}$ is a number of less than $p$ digit, which must be smaller than $\overline{D[i..j]}$.
  There are at most $n$ choices for the gap with at most $n$ possible choices for $s$ for each gap. It takes $O(n^2)$ to list them.
- For each $s=0, 1, \cdots, i-p-1$, we can check whether $\overline{D[s..s+p]}<\overline{D[i,j]}$ in $O(n)$ time by comparing their digits one by one starting from the most significant digit.
  There are at most $n$ choices for $s$. So we can list all $(s,s+p)$'s such that $\overline{D[s..s+gap]}<\overline{D[i,j]}$ in $O(n^2)$ time.

Once we know all possible $(k,l)$'s, it takes $O(n^2)$ time to compute $DP[i][j]$ using the recurrence relation.

Hence it takes $O(n^2)\cdot O(n^2)=O(n^4)$ time to compute all subproblems. It takes $O(n^2)$ to compute the final answer. Hence, it takes $O(n^4)$ time to run the algorithm.

Comment: You can actually compare two substrings in $O(\log n)$ by preprocessing the original string using a suffix tree. The comparison becomes an LCA operation on the suffix tree, so your algorithm is actually $O(n^3 \log(n))$.

Comment: Well said. The exercises also reads "the fastest algorithm I know for this problem runs in $O(n^{3/2}\log n)$ time". If someone asks what could be that fastest algorithm, I could write an answer.